# Evaluation of $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{nx} dx$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $a>0$, how to find
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{a}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(nx)}{nx} dx\; ?
$$
Also, what will happened if $a=0$?

**My attempt**. Let $u=nx$: then the limit of the integral would be the following
$$
\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n} \lim_{b\to \infty} \int_{na}^{nb} \dfrac{\sin(u)}{u} du.
$$
However, I'm not sure this is the good way to find the answer, because I don't know how to compute this integral.

Comment: Please show us your ideas and trys.

Comment: Maybe check out the [sine integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral).

Comment: @IonelaBuciu sorry I'm the beginner, and I didn't know the rules, I'll post my attempt later!

Comment: @MengchunZhang Thanks! It seems that the answer are both 0. Right?

Comment: @OneLamp Yes indeed, you got it!